# grep --byte-offset doesn't give me the bytes offset?

Tags: grep

I run

```
grep -b --byte-offset 'EXTH' Agent_of_Change.mobi
```

but I only get "Binary file Agent_of_Change.mobi matches".
How can I get the bytes offset instead?

Answer (score 7):

`grep` would, by default, only returns *matches* for binary files.

You would need to tell `grep` to treat binary files as text.

```
grep -a -b 'EXTH' Agent_of_Change.mobi
```

However, `grep` warns you of the possible consequences:

```
          option.  If TYPE is text, grep processes a binary file as if  it
          were  text;  this is equivalent to the -a option.  Warning: grep
          --binary-files=text might output binary garbage, which can  have
          nasty  side  effects  if  the  output  is  a terminal and if the
          terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.
```

Comment: hi, I still don't get the output I need. -a gives no output. -o and -b doesn't change the output (specified in the question).

Comment: @Patrick Did you try `strings yourfile | grep searchstring`?  If that doesn't produce an output, chances are that `grep` wouldn't either.

Comment: Yes, it gives me the output

Comment: @Patrick In that event, `grep` should as well.  Don't use `-o` (in case you are).  `grep -a -b searchstring file | cut -d: -f1` should give you the offset that you are looking for.

Comment: grep EXTH Agent_of_Change.mobi gives the correct output ("Binary file .. matches").

Comment: grep --byte-offset EXTH Agent_of_Change.mobi does give the same output but I don't see the offset

Comment: @Patrick Try piping to `cut` as suggested in the comment above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it. "grep -a -b EXTH Agent_of_Change.mobi | cut -d: -f1" gives me no output.

Answer (score 4):

Add `-a` to force printing of matches even if they don't seem printable.

Add `-o` and it'll only print the "EXTH" instead of the line. That also changes the byte offset - it'll print the offset of the "EXTH" instead of the offset of the beginning of the line containing the "EXTH". If the file isn't actually made of lines, this will be an improvement!

Or use `perl -n0777e 'print pos()-length($&),"\n" while /EXTH/g'` to replace your GNU grep dependency with a dependency on something more universal... (Warning: slurps whole file into memory, may be unpleasant for large files)

Comment: Does grep load all file in memory as well?

Comment: grep works on one line at a time, so it doesn't load the whole file but can load some big chunks if the input isn't text.

Comment: I've tried grep -o --byte-offset... to get the offset of the exact word (this is what I need), but i get no output. (The word is there I'm sure).

Comment: Is maybe some encoding issue related? It is  MOBI e-book file. It is a binary file, with some text content here and there

Comment: @Patrick, what does `command grep -abo EXTH file.mobi` return?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas No output.

Comment: @Patrick, and `grep EXTH file.mobi` returns _file matches_? Sounds like a bug in your `grep`. What's `grep --version`.

Comment: perl looking better yet?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The latest command gives "Binary file Agent_of_Change.mobi matches". grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: I would prefer to use unix bash commands, because I need to run it from an OSX app

Comment: +1 Perl method is excellent for recent OS X which includes grep 2.5.1, which has a bug that returns always 0 for --byte-offset. I subtracted length($matchString) rather than 1 to get the offset at the start of string rather than end.

Comment: @IvanX Yes, that `-1` was a bug. Or maybe it was what I meant when I wrote it, but I don't remember why. Changed it to `length($&)`. Thanks for the tip.